# Where can I find spark.driver.maxresultsize property in Cloudera manager?

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera-manager

Can anyone provide the location where I can change the value of the environment variable spark.driver.maxresultsize in Cloudera Manager?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Actually you may use the Spark web ui to see the environment variables which may be found at http://your-master-node:4040,  and provided you have already set your spark.driver.maxresultsize variable in your properties file (spark-defaults.conf).

> The application web UI at http://:4040 lists Spark properties in the “Environment” tab. This is a useful place to check to make sure that your properties have been set correctly. Note that only values explicitly specified through spark-defaults.conf, SparkConf, or the command line will appear. For all other configuration properties, you can assume the default value is used.